# What is the term to say a carriage going in reverse?

Tags: word-choice

Suppose you are in a driving a carriage on a narrow street and you see another carriage coming.

Both carriages will not fit on the street, and you have no space to make a U turn, so, you decide to pull your horses back, making the carriage run backwards...

What is the word to describe that?

I thought about reverse the carriage but it sounds to me that the word reverse also mean U turn.

I was wondering if there is a word or term that can only represent what I have described?

Comment: I would say you're *backing up* the carriage.

Comment: As everyone knows, being conversant with livery paraphernalia, that this is impossible. Horses cannot walk a carriage backwards because the harnessing only would allow them to push back with their haunches, which horses just do not do. I can only surmise that you are mad.

Comment: @Mitch -- Well, that situation certainly happened many times, especially in the narrow streets of London and other cities. While what you're saying is true, if you had two carriages coming from opposite directions where neither could pass, something was done. They weren't just stuck there forever until the horses died and they with their carriages decomposed into the ground. It seems to me it would have still involved backing the horses up by having them walk backwards but doing so while someone pushed the carriage backwards at the same time to keep it ahead of the horses' hind quarters.

Comment: @Billy I think they just spun a coin and ate one of the horses. It was the quickest way to clear the blockage.

Comment: @Billy Oh. Right. Sure. Then just __back up__ the whole thing.

Comment: To me it seems both Hot Licks, grammatically and Mitch, technically are correct and of course, Billy, that happened many times…

I won't bother to quote them but I think some records show people being killed in such confrontations.

More usually, rather than shoot each other, they'd somehow decide which one should beg or pay some by-standers to back up one of the carriages.
Still the term would be, as Hot Licks said, "back(ing) up…" *How* anyone ever backed up a carriage has nothing to do with language.